# (Solving SQL problem using Pandas) from the given pandas dataframe, find the overall acceptance rate of requests rounded to 2 decimals

Tags: python, pandas

I am challenging myself to solve a SQL data manipulation problem using Pandas. Below are the Pandas Dataframes;

```
friend_request = pd.DataFrame({'sender_id':[1,1,1,2,3],
                               'send_to_id':[2,3,4,3,4],
                               'request_date':['2016_06-01','2016_06-01','2016_06-01','2016_06-02','2016_06-09']})

request_accepted = pd.DataFrame({'requester_id':[1,1,2,3,3],
                                 'accepter_id':[2,3,3,4,4],
                                 'accept_date':['2016_06-03','2016_06-08','2016_06-08','2016_06-09','2016_06-10']})
```

You would transform the 'request_date' and 'accept_date' to Pandas datetime variables.

```
friend_request['request_date']=friend_request['request_date'].replace(to_replace='_',value = '-',regex=True)
request_accepted['accept_date']=request_accepted['accept_date'].replace(to_replace='_',value = '-',regex=True)
```

With this, you have the pandas dataframes with proper dtypes. Now, how would you go about getting the finding the overall acceptance rate of requests rounded to 2 decimals, which is the number of acceptance divide the number of requests?

Using SQL syntax,

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(
        ifnull(
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT requester_id,accepter_id
              FROM request_accepted) as numerator)/
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id,send_to_id
              FROM friend_request) as denominator),0),2
            ) AS acceptance_rate
```

This is looking at all unique pairs of (requester_id,accepter_id) and comparing it against the (sender_id, send_to_id). 
Now, will there be a similar way to solve this problem using Pandas?

Expected outcome is 0.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
numerator = len(request_accepted.groupby(['requester_id', 'accepter_id']))
denominator = len(friend_request.groupby(['sender_id', 'send_to_id']))

print('{:.2f}'.format(round(numerator/denominator, 2)) if numerator/denominator else 0)

0.80
```